# Deduce a frame condition for a dual Riesz basis

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, alternative-proof

Let $\{ f_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a Riesz basis with Riesz bounds $A$ and $B,$ and $\{ g_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be its dual Riesz basis. Show that 
$$\frac{1}{B} \leq \| g_k \|^2 \leq \frac{1}{A}.$$

My approach: Since $\{ f_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a a Riesz basis the dual Riesz basis is $\{ S^{-1} f_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty},$ where $S:\mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ is a frame operator: 
$$Sf=TT^*f=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\langle f, f_k \right\rangle f_k .$$
Since $S$ is invertible and self-adjoint, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |\left\langle f, S^{-1}f_k \right\rangle|^2
 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |\left\langle S^{-1}f, f_k \right\rangle|^2 
 \leq B \|~ S^{-1}f \|^2 \leq  B ~ \| S^{-1} \|^2 ~ \| f \|^2.$$

Further, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\langle f, S^{-1}f_k \right\rangle S^{-1}f_k = S^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\langle S^{-1}f, f_k \right\rangle f_k  
=S^{-1} S S^{-1} f =S^{-1}f.$$

From this, how to continue and get the desired inequality. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A Riesz basis $\{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with bounds $A,B > 0$ is, in particular, a frame with frame bounds $A,B$. The dual Riesz basis $\{S^{-1} f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the canonical dual frame of $\{f_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, and hence has frame bounds $B^{-1}, A^{-1}$.